# replace named keys with numbered keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

What is the most efficient and concise way to replace named keys with numbered keys in a multidimensional array?

My array:

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array 
        (
            [Property] => Brock
            [Meint. Type] => grounds
            [Maint. Task] => plow snow
            [Status] => cancelled
            [Started] =>
            [Completed] =>
            [Comments] =>
        )

    [1] => Array 
        (
            [Property] => Brock
            [Meint. Type] => grounds
            [Maint. Task] => plow snow
            [Status] => pending
            [Started] => 2010-01-16
            [Completed] =>
            [Comments] =>
        )

    [2] => Array
        ( 
            [Property] => Brock
            [Mains. Type] => grounds
            [Maint. Task] => plow snow
            [Status] => complete
            [Started] => 2010-01-16
            [Completed] => 2010-01-16
            [Comments] =>
        )

    [3] => Array 
        (
            [Property] => Brock
            [Mains. Type] => grounds
            [Maint. Task] => plow snow
            [Status] => in progress
            [Started] => 2014-01-16
            [Completed] => 2014-01-16
            [Comments] =>
        )

    [4] => Array
```

The goal is to replace [Property] with [0], [Maint. Type] with [1] (this should have square brackets around it, they are being automatically removed), [Maint. Task] with [2], [Status] with [3] etc. for each of the sub arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
$modified_array = array_map('array_values', $arr);
```

Explanation: [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) applies [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values) function to every element from `$arr` array.